# Store absolute last list item, of each top level list, in a nested list

Tags: jquery

I have a nested HTML list and I'm trying to get the `.last()` `<li>` of the top level `<ul>`'s.

Here's what it looks like with Jade

```
#menu
  ul: li
    a(href='#') Work (Top Level List 1)
    ul: li
      a(href='#') Project 1
      ul: li
        a(href='#') Project 1.1
        ul: li
          a(href='#') Project 1.1.1
          ul: li
            a(href='#') Project 1.1.1.1
            ul
              li: a(href='#link') Project 1.1.1.1.1
              li: a(href='#link') Project 1.1.1.1.2
              li: a(href='#link') Project 1.1.1.1.3
            li: a(href='#link') Project 1.1.1.2
            li: a(href='#link') Project 1.1.1.3
          li: a(href='#link') Project 1.1.2
          li: a(href='#link') Project 1.1.3
        li: a(href='#link') Project 1.2
        li: a(href='#link') Project 1.3 <- (Last li of top level list)
    li
      a(href='#') Resume (Top Level List 2)
      ul
        li: a(href='#link') Resume 1
        li: a(href='#link') Resume 2
        li: a(href='#link') Resume 3 <- (Last li of top level list)
    li
      a(href='#') Contact (Top Level List 3)
      ul
        li: a(href='#link') Contact 1
        li: a(href='#link') Contact 2
        li: a(href='#link') Contact 3 <- (Last li of top level list)
```

I got my desired `<li>`'s with this jQuery (using CoffeeScript).

```
$li = $this.find('li')

$liLastChild = $li.find(':last-child').children('a')

$scope = $this.find($li).find($ul)
$scopeNot = $scope.find($li).find($ul)

$this.find($scope).not($scopeNot).each ->
  $(this).find($liLastChild).last().css('background', 'orange')
```

But I need to check against these selectors using something like:

```
if $(this).is($orangeListItem)
```

When I take out the each like:

```
$this.find($scope).not($scopeNot)
  .find($liLastChild).last().css('background', 'orange')
```

jQuery gets the last `<li>` at the very very end, instead of scoping it to the desired `<ul>`.

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do, preferably without `.each()`, so I can store this into `$orangeListItem`?

[Here's a CodePen.](http://codepen.io/dustindowell/pen/NPOVPe)

EDIT: I halfway solved my problem. I'm still open to improving this. I'm not sure how nice of a solution this is.

I stored the each loop in variable, then I use `:last` to get the last list item. `.last()` won't work for some reason? It also won't work if I add `:last` inside the loop.

This is what the each loop looks like now.

```
$lastLast = $this.find($scope).not($scopeNot).each ->
  $(this).find($liLastChild) # Gather items

$lastLast = $lastLast.find(':last') # Get last list item

$lastLast.css('background', 'orange') # Make them orange
```

[Here's an updated CodePen.](http://codepen.io/dustindowell/pen/GgPYrM?editors=101)

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use something like this:

```
var $targets = $('#menu > ul > li > ul > li:last-child').not(':has(ul)');
```

This makes heavy use of direct [child selectors](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) and then jQuery's [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) filter to exclude any top-level li elements if they have a nested ul (e.g. "Project 1")

You can see an example here on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codebyren/v914u0ty/1/).

**EDIT:**

> Well, the tricky part is getting "project 1.3" also, or whatever the last list item is in the first list "Work". I need the absolute last li for each top level list.

Sorry, overlooked that one. I don't think a single CSS selector would be able to include that item then. How about this:

```
// This variable will store all target <li> as we find them
var $targets = $();

// Loop through each top level <li> to grab the last <li> nested within each
$('#menu > ul > li').each(function () {

    var $nested_li = $(this).find('li');

    // If any nested <li> are found then we want the last <li>
    if ($nested_li.length) {

        $targets = $targets.add($nested_li.last());
    }
});

// The $targets variable should now contain all relevant <li> items
$targets.css('background', 'orange');
```

I've updated the [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codebyren/v914u0ty/2/) too.

Comment: Well, the tricky part is getting "project 1.3" also, or whatever the last list item is in the first list "Work". I need the absolute last `<li>` for each top level list.

Comment: Ahhh. Awesome! That's perfect. Much cleaner. I figured it was too complicated than just a single selector. I'll come back and upvote you once I get rep.